# SLDS and Bootstrap Conflicting

Tags: visualforce, slds, bootstrap

I have a button which has a `bootstrap glyph icon` applied to it and for some reason it is not working as desired.

It is conflicting with the SLDS css, it seems.

Can someone tell me how can I achieve the bootstrap functionality?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm repeater-prev">
    <span class="chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous Page</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Quick question, have you tried to use the SLDS approach to icons? Perhaps that would be an easier solution?

Comment: Actually I thought about it first but the requirement is to use bootstrap

Comment: I don't know enough CSS to help you more than that. But mixing two frameworks always carries the danger of conflict. I would advise that, if this is not a simple fix, you explore the possibility of doing it differently

Comment: If you are not using the namespaced slds, try that. That may solve css class conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Lightning Salesforce Design System allows you to generate namespaced styles.
https://tools.lightningdesignsystem.com/css-customizer
In fact you will need to wrap your HTML in `<div class="my-slds">`.

Same trick is appliable to Bootstrap you can try to use bootstrap-sf1.
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/bootstrap-sf1